# Why do we need clientID and clientSecret

Tags: google-oauth, passport.js

I recently have implemented GoogleStrategy using passportJS and I am successful implementing it.

But why do I need to registering the app in [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and get the clientID and client Secret.

I am not successful in finding why it is needed. Could anyone please let me know why and when is it required?

Comment: This link gives a simplified explanation of how OAuth2 works. http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Answer (score 8):

You *don't* need both. There are many different OAuth grant types, and many of them do not require the client_secret.

Using the client secret is recommended for server-side apps (where the end user does not have access the client secret) because it is more secure. It is not recommended for client-side apps; those apps can be decompiled, thus leaking the client_secret.

Answer (score 1):

Your clientID is used so that Google can identify your application and allow the usage of Google APIs and services as appropriate. It is all for authentication and authorization so that you can get the proper permissions and accesses to whatever Google APIs and services.

Your clientSecret is used to hold slightly more confidential information, such as your api usage, traffic information, and billing information.

Comment: `clientSecret` doesn't **hold** anything. It's something only you and Google know, used to verify that your requests made with the `clientID` are authorized.

Comment: Perhaps hold wasn't the right wording for it, but it can be used to access more private information as per the warning here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#acquiring

Comment: Yes. Like a password, the secret grants access to more privileged actions, without holding anything.

Comment: downvote was unwarranted, as this explanation is ok. The key point is that Google needs to identify the application, and authenticate that something claiming to be the application is genuine. ClientID is the identifier, Client Secret (in conjunction with configured redirect urls) is the authentication token for server apps, and referrer url is the authentication token for JS client apps.

Comment: @Andy I saw no warnings @ that link, sir